# Logged User and Registered User login and register Functionality

Tags: java, jsp

The below JSP sample code is: If the user is logged in then do the first statement and if the user is registered then do the second statement and if both fail then do the third one.

```
if (loggedUser != null && registeredUser == null) {%>
 <p>You are logged in as <%= loggedUser.getName()%></p>
 <p><a href="logoutController.jsp">Logout</a> | <a 
 href="editUser.jsp">My Account</a></p>
 <%@include file="searchItem.jsp" %>

 <%} else if (registeredUser!=null && loggedUser==null) {%>
 <p>You are logged in as <%= registeredUser.getName()%></p>
 <p><a href="logoutController.jsp">Logout</a> | <a href="editUser.jsp">My Account</a></p>
 <%@include file="searchItem.jsp" %>

 <%} else {%>
 <p>You are not logged in</p>
 <p><a href="login.jsp">Login</a> | <a href="register.jsp">Register</a> </p>
 <%@include file="searchItem.jsp" %>
 <% }%>
```

When I run this code then it runs the third statement but the user is registered and is logged in.

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to achieve in first if second if and third if statement. Also user to be logged in has to be registered ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess only registered user can login...
so... first if is wrong.

it must be:

```
if (loggedUser != null && registeredUser != null)
```

or just

```
if (loggedUser != null)
```